# connect php to microsoft sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've been through almost all the solutions listed for connecting php to microsoft SQL server.

I'm using windows 64 bit machine with xampp installed and trying to connect to microsoft sql server management studio.

I've added php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll to C:\xampp\php\ext

I've also added the below lines to php.ini available in C:\xampp\php\php.ini :

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll ;added on 03-09-2018 for connecting to ms sql
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll ;added on 03-09-2018 for connecting to ms sql

However, i keep getting the Fatal error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14

<?php

$serverName = "XXXX";
$uid = "abcd";
$pwd = "Abcd1234";
$databaseName = "databasename";


$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);

    /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM SRC_transaction";

/* Execute the query. */

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

if ( $stmt )
{
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
/* Free statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Comment: Just in case (been there, done that): have you restarted Apache from the Xampp control panel?

Comment: You may have 2 php.ini, one in php directory and one in apache directory. Also you can check with phpinfo(); loaded extensions.

Comment: @Loek : restarting did not help

Comment: @D.Dimitrov : what should i look for in phpinfo() ?

Comment: @irfanharun the `php.ini` you've edited is probably not the one loaded by Apache. In `phpinfo()` you can see which extensions are loaded. If your custom .dll files are not listed, you need to add them to the `php.ini` file loaded by Apache (location is also on the `phpinfo()` screen.

Comment: i seem to have only one php.ini in my setup https://postimg.cc/image/57zghesnv/